# How to use the result of a function to another function in python?

Tags: python, self

please help I was trying to create Class and Object about pay roll but I got stuck when I tried to use another function to complete the computation for my another funtion

I cant think of any idea how can i use the result of hourly rate to compute my overtime pay, to compute my overtime pay it needs the result of hourly rate and multiply them in my overtime hours

```
employee1 = Employee("001", "Joss Rees", 700, 24, 4, 500, 1)

class Employee:

    def __init__(self, employee_number, name, daily_rate, days_worked, overtime_hours, cash_advance, days_absent):
        self.employee_number = employee_number
        self.name = name
        self.daily_rate = daily_rate
        self.days_worked = days_worked
        self.overtime_hours = overtime_hours
        self.cash_advance = cash_advance
        self.days_absent = days_absent

    def hourly_rate(self):

        return print(self.daily_rate / 8)

    def monthly_rate(self):
        return print(self.daily_rate * self.days_worked)

    #heres the problem 
    def overtime_pay(self):
        return self.hourly_rate(self) * self.overtime_hours
```

Comment: Don't print the return values, just return them. If you want to print them, print in the calling function instead.

Comment: hello thank you ill do that but how can I print the result of my overtime pay if I need to use the result of another function which is hourly rate?

Comment: No problem with printing if you want to but after the print return the value

Comment: Don't ever `return print(...)` -- it'll always be `None`.

Comment: thankyou guys it worked ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

`return print(self.daily_rate / 8)` will return the return of `print` and since `print` function return `None`, you dont need to use this and just simply return the values without print fucntion.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, employee_number, name, daily_rate, days_worked, overtime_hours, cash_advance, days_absent):
        self.employee_number = employee_number
        self.name = name
        self.daily_rate = daily_rate
        self.days_worked = days_worked
        self.overtime_hours = overtime_hours
        self.cash_advance = cash_advance
        self.days_absent = days_absent

    def hourly_rate(self):
        return self.daily_rate / 8

    def monthly_rate(self):
        return self.daily_rate * self.days_worked

    #heres the problem 
    def overtime_pay(self):
        return self.hourly_rate() * self.overtime_hours
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of problems with your code. First, `employee1` needs to be moved below the `Employee` class, else you should get a `NameError`.

Then, why are you passing `self` to your methods ? This happens automatically (so in the end the method receives the `self` argument twice and you should get a `TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`).
Lastly, you need to stop printing values inside `return`'s. Reason: The `print` function returns `None` - so you will never get the value out of that function. Also, a function / method that calculates something normally does not print its result - this is normally left to the calling function. So, remove the `print`'s you have right now, and rather print them in the `overtime_pay` method, like this:

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, employee_number, name, daily_rate, days_worked, overtime_hours, cash_advance, days_absent):
        self.employee_number = employee_number
        self.name = name
        self.daily_rate = daily_rate
        self.days_worked = days_worked
        self.overtime_hours = overtime_hours
        self.cash_advance = cash_advance
        self.days_absent = days_absent

    def hourly_rate(self):

        return self.daily_rate / 8

    def monthly_rate(self):
        return self.daily_rate * self.days_worked

    def overtime_pay(self):
        return self.hourly_rate(self) * self.overtime_hours

employee1 = Employee("001", "Joss Rees", 700, 24, 4, 500, 1)
print(employee1.overtime_pay())
```

Comment: i see thank you for pointing out my mistakes and thankyouuuu it finally worked